# How to check whether user has logged into facebook native app?

Tags: android, facebook, session, native

How to check whether user has logged into facebook native app using facebook sdk from our android app(as iphone checks the status from settings app)?
without using any server calls

Comment: why down vote? i have seen many answers but none of them were offline

Comment: which SDK  version ?

Comment: facebook sdk 3+ version

Comment: did you try for active session ?

Comment: active session only works when user has pervious logged in to facebook using our app

Answer (score 0):

try using facebook Session ....

```
Session fb_session= null;

fb_session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if( fb_session != null )
    {
        if( fb_session.isOpened() )
        {

     //do your stuff here......

        }
    }
```

Hope it helps...!

Comment: it only works when user has active session with our app

Comment: it does not check with native app status
it only checks last logged status using our app

Comment: in your FacebookSDK in LoginButton class at line number :835 you will get the answer.......there is complete code how login button take session from native app.......OR the second idea is to introduce an LoginButton ,you will get session after clicking on it..